# Can i stream camera to a remote server?

Tags: camera, raspicam

In my project i have to stream a low FPS and low-resolution live camera to an external server, because i am not able to port forward the pi's network.
Is it possible to set up a remote server and stream to it?
I can port forward the server.

Comment: There are many ways - icecast, HLS, MPEG-DASH, RTMP, RTSP, FTL, SRT - not sure why you would need to "port forward the server" - since most servers that are external to your own network would likely NOT be behind NAT

Comment: The answer is Yes and from your description I assume that the receiving server is behind NAT and that's the reason for "port forwarding". An example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWwZF_zVf00